# How to g++ a C++ program using boost/asio.hpp file?

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following example program

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp

When I execute, I get this error ..

```
$ g++ sync_client.cpp -I usr/include/boost

/tmp/cc3eDbiW.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
sync_client.cpp:(.text+0xd61): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
sync_client.cpp:(.text+0xd6d): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
sync_client.cpp:(.text+0xd79): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/cc3eDbiW.o: In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
sync_client.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/cc3eDbiW.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
sync_client.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[boost::asio::error::get_system_category()]+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/cc3eDbiW.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr_create(unsigned int&)':
sync_client.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail20posix_tss_ptr_createERj[boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr_create(unsigned int&)]+0x19): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/tmp/cc3eDbiW.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::~posix_thread()':
sync_client.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail12posix_threadD2Ev[_ZN5boost4asio6detail12posix_threadD5Ev]+0x26): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/tmp/cc3eDbiW.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::join()':
sync_client.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail12posix_thread4joinEv[boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::join()]+0x2b): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/tmp/cc3eDbiW.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()':
sync_client.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_15task_io_serviceEE7contextEED2Ev[_ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_15task_io_serviceEE7contextEED5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/tmp/cc3eDbiW.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::strand_service::strand_impl>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()':
sync_client.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_14strand_service11strand_implEE7contextEED2Ev[_ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_14strand_service11strand_implEE7contextEED5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the correct compiler command?

Comment: Is there some particularly good reason you're still using Boost 1.45? That's well over 3 years old...

Comment: What is the IDE? There are flags to tell it where to pick up things

Comment: no the example is from boost 1.45 I am using 1.55 i think

Comment: have you tried plain gcc? it should form the proper call to g++

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ sync_client.cpp -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -o sync_client
```

And then:

```
./sync_client
```

You may have to add `-lpthread` to the compilation command, it seems that your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `ld.so.conf` is not configured properly.

Note: There's no need to add `-I /usr/include/boost` to the command line.

**Update:**

The command `ls -l /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams*` should output something like this:

```
... /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so -> libboost_iostreams.so.1.55.0*
... /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.55.0*
```

If that's the case, try running `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: this is the problem it cannot find boost_iostreams or boost_system .. i used apt-get and compiled libboost-dev from source

Comment: Try installing [libboost-all-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libboost-all-dev), not need to install from source, btw.

Comment: sorry i did install libboost-all-dev. My ld.so.conf is this : include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set

Comment: Check adding `-I /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/` to the command line. Installing from sources usually uses `/usr/local` as install root insted of `/usr`.

Comment: I solved it by doing apt-get install libboost-system-dev and then apt-get install libboost-thread-dev and then g++ sync_client -lboost_system -pthread

Comment: But [`libboost-all-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libboost-all-dev) is a virtual package which depends on all of them, it's weird that all those dependencies were not installed automatically.

Comment: that makes sense. however, as far as i can remember i had to explicitly install libboost-system-dev.